# storing data in cloud in the form of tables of an Android application

Tags: android, database, android-database

I have developed an android application in which I am storing data in the form of tables. Now I want to store the same data in the form of tables on cloud.So that I have to write SQL queries to deal with the database.And whoever makes changes in the in the database , that change should be reflected in the application on refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an [openshift.com](https://www.openshift.com/) account. They are providing some well known databases like MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, SQLite etc. and programming languages like Java, Ruby, Node.js, Python, PHP etc. you can use it as back-end for your android application only thing is that you have to code your back-end part for database operations using any of your favorite language.